# How to filter data by average with api platform?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have two entities `Games` and `Rate` :

```
class Games
{
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Rate::class, mappedBy="game", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    private $rates;
}
```

And

```
class Rate
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Games::class, inversedBy="rates")
    */
    private $game;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $value;
}
```

I want to create a custom filter that selects the best game, I mean Games which has the highest average
or in SQL :

```
SELECT avg(r.value) FROM games g JOIN rate r ON g.id = r.game_id
GROUP BY r.game_id
```

so I create it :

```
class RateFilter extends AbstractContextAwareFilter
{
    protected $parameterName = 'rate';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = [])
    {
        if (isset($context['filters']) && is_array($context['filters'])) {
            if (!empty($context['filters'][$this->parameterName])) {
                $rate = $context['filters'][$this->parameterName];
            } else {
                return;
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }

        $queryBuilder
            ->Join('o.rates', 'r')
            ->andHaving($queryBuilder->expr()->avg('r.value'))
            ->groupBy('o.id');
    }
}
```

but when I use my custom filter : `[GET] /games?rate=game`

I get this error :

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 163: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=,
> !=, got 'ORDER'

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your query ? `having` clause should do what exactly ? Get those with an average above `$rate` ?

Comment: @DylanKas Calculate the mean and sort

Comment: @DylanKas I want to it : SELECT avg(r.value) FROM games g JOIN rate r ON g.id = r.game_id
GROUP BY r.game_id